# Rails 4 image_tag('image.png') not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 2.3 app that has these image files in the public directory:

```
public/images/tools/projects.png
public/images/tools/languages.png
public/images/tools/repositories.png
```

I went directly into these files copied the contents and then pasted them in my rails 4 app in these directories:

```
app/assets/images/tools/projects.png
app/assets/images/tools/languages.png
app/assets/images/tools/repositories.png
```

In my view file I refer to these files like so: (HAML file)

```
 = image_tag('tools/projects.png', alt: 'Projects')
```

When I do this my image is broken. I've tried changing the path in image tag to this:

```
 = image_tag('app/assets/images/tools/projects.png', alt: 'Projects')
 = image_tag('projects.png', alt: 'Projects')
 = image_tag('assets/images/tools/projects.png', alt: 'Projects')
 = image_tag('images/tools/projects.png', alt: 'Projects')
```

None of these options are working. All the other images are working. I'm assuming that copy and pasting the image contents was not the right thing to do.

```
8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452 etc.
```

I've copied and pasted multiple times so I'm certain that I have all the codes.

------EDIT-----

I tried the same source paths except I forgot to add a slash at the beginning. However it still failed.

```
/images/tools/projects.png
```

Comment: I'm using a `Rails 4` app and have my images in `/public/assets/images/foo.png` I'm not sure about putting them in `app/assets` usually that's for JavaScript or CSS

Comment: Production or development?

Comment: This looks like raw image file hex data "8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452..." How did you copy the images?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys. I'm in my development environment (Jorge de los Santos) and I read that the preferred place to place images is in the app/assets directory for the asset pipeline (SuckerForMayhem)

Comment: Thanks for the reply also Valerie. I basically just placed my cursor at the top of the image file highlighted all the way down to the bottom and copied and pasted from my rails 2.3 app and then just pasted what was copied in an empty projects.png,repositories.png, and languages.png file.

Comment: That is an unusual way to copy a png. Depending on the way you copied, there is potential for bit loss or truncation based on character sets, etc. Can you open the new files you created in an image editor?  What I'm getting at here is that even with correct paths to the images, if your image files are not recognized as image format, they won't load. A simple test would be to copy the image files using a copy command: cp (asterisk).png  /dest/(asterisk).png . (my asterisks were altered by form.)

Comment: Hmm... I tried cp'ing the image files from the old app to the new app, but that didn't work either. Tricky problem.

Comment: try this `= image_tag('tools/projects.png', alt: 'Projects')` and run `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: So, what do you see as the image url if you look either at page source or with a browser's debugger? Are there any console error codes on page where one of these images is referenced?

Comment: The rake assets:precompile command worked. Now the images are showing. Thanks everyone for the help.